# How to handle SQLAlchemy Connections in ProcessPool?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, rabbitmq, python-multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I have a reactor that fetches messages from a RabbitMQ broker and triggers worker methods to process these messages in a process pool, something like this:

[image: Reactor]

This is implemented using python `asyncio`, `loop.run_in_executor()` and `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`.

Now I want to access the database in the worker methods using SQLAlchemy. Mostly the processing will be very straightforward and quick CRUD operations.

The reactor will process 10-50 messages per second in the beginning, so it is not acceptable to open a new database connection for every request. Rather I would like to maintain one persistent connection per process.

My questions are: How can I do this? Can I just store them in a global variable? Will the SQA connection pool handle this for me? How to clean up when the reactor stops?

**[Update]**

- The database is MySQL with InnoDB.

**Why choosing this pattern with a process pool?**

The current implementation uses a different pattern where each consumer runs in its own thread. Somehow this does not work very well. There are already about 200 consumers each running in their own thread, and the system is growing quickly. To scale better, the idea was to separate concerns and to consume messages in an I/O loop and delegate the processing to a pool. Of course, the performance of the whole system is mainly I/O bound. However, CPU is an issue when processing large result sets.

The other reason was "ease of use." While the connection handling and consumption of messages is implemented asynchronously, the code in the worker can be synchronous and simple.

Soon it became evident that accessing remote systems through persistent network connections from within the worker are an issue. This is what the CommunicationChannels are for: Inside the worker, I can grant requests to the message bus through these channels.

One of my current ideas is to handle DB access in a similar way: Pass statements through a queue to the event loop where they are sent to the DB. However, I have no idea how to do this with SQLAlchemy. 
Where would be the entry point? 
Objects need to be `pickled` when they are passed through a queue. How do I get such an object from an SQA query?
The communication with the database has to work asynchronously in order not to block the event loop. Can I use e.g. aiomysql as a database driver for SQA?

Comment: So each worker is its own process?  Can't share connections then, so maybe you should instantiate each (local) SQA pools with max 1 or 2 connection limits.  Then observe, maybe via database (which db ?) what connections are being spawned/killed. Having gotten badly burned on just this - what you **don't** want to do is implement your own naive conn pool on top of SQA's. Or try to identify if an SQA conn is closed or not.

Comment: @JLPeyret: I updated the question with the info you requested. And no ... I'm not planing to implement my own connection pool.

Comment: So, I think I remember that connections can't cross processes (in the OS sense of the word, to differentiate from threads).  And I know connections don't pickle well at all. You should be able to message "dead" (string) sql statements but I believe you'll have a hard time passing around db conns, I think including probably SQA results.  Speculation on my end, but with some extent of playing with odd SQA usage to justify it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your requirement of **one database connection per process-pool process** can be easily satisfied if some care is taken on how you instantiate the `session`, assuming you are working with the orm, in the worker processes.

A simple solution would be to have a global [session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html) which you reuse across requests:

```
# db.py
engine = create_engine("connection_uri", pool_size=1, max_overflow=0)
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

And on the worker task:

```
# task.py
from db import engine, DBSession
def task():
    DBSession.begin() # each task will get its own transaction over the global connection
    ...
    DBSession.query(...)
    ...
    DBSession.close() # cleanup on task end
```

Arguments `pool_size` and `max_overflow` [customize](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#connection-pool-configuration) the default [QueuePool](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#sqlalchemy.pool.QueuePool) used by create_engine.`pool_size` will make sure your process only keeps 1 connection alive per process in the process pool.

If you want it to reconnect you can use `DBSession.remove()` which will remove the session from the registry and will make it reconnect at the next DBSession usage. You can also use the `recycle` argument of [Pool](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#sqlalchemy.pool.Pool) to make the connection reconnect after the specified amount of time.

During development/debbuging you can use [AssertionPool](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#sqlalchemy.pool.AssertionPool) which will raise an exception if more than one connection is checked-out from the pool, see [switching pool implementations](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#switching-pool-implementations) on how to do that.

Comment: So you basically you suggest that I should not worry because the SQA pool will handle that right out of the box? This would be nice! I will migrate our main app with +200 consumers and +20000 lines of code to the new software architecture within the next few days and see if it works.

Comment: @roman Good luck with your refactor, if you have any issues don't hesitate to post a comment here, and if you feel that i covered your question it would be nice to mark this as accepted :) .

Comment: Seems to work fine so far! :) This section in the docs should be mentioned I think http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/core/pooling.html?highlight=multiprocessing#using-connection-pools-with-multiprocessing. One has to take special care regarding multiprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

@roman: Nice challenge you have there.

I have being in a similar scenario before so here is my *2 cents*: unless this consumer only *"read"* and *"write"* the message, without do any real proccessing of it, you could *re-design* this consumer as a consumer/producer that will *consume* the message, it will process the message and then will put result in another queue, that queue (processed messages for say) could be read by 1..N non-pooled asynchronous processes that would have open the DB connection in it's own entire life-cycle.

I can extend my answer, but I don't know if this approach fits for your needs, if so, I can give you more detail about the extended design.

Comment: I was considering such an approach however I think it will be very hard to get the transaction handling right. I think I don't want to try building my own distributed transaction manager.

Answer (score 0):

An approach that has served me really well is to use a webserver to handle and scale the process pool. flask-sqlalchemy even in its default state will keep a connection pool and not close each connection on each request response cycle.

The asyncio executor can just call url end points to execute your functions. The added benefit is that because all processes doing the work are behind a url you can trivially scale your worker pool across mutliple machines, adding more processes via gunicorn or one of the other many methods to scale a simple wsgi server. Plus you get all the fault tolerant goodness.

The downside is that you might be passing more information across the network. However as you say the problem is CPU bound and you will probably be passing much more data to and from the database.

Comment: When I say CPU is an issue, I don't mean the major work load is CPU bound! It is not ... As with the other approach above, I see a serious issues with transaction handling here. To have a stateless network connection in between the business logic and the persistence layer sounds scary.